# Do anyone know how to extract Image coordinate from Marmot dataset?

Tags: python, hex, endianness

Marmot is a document image dataset (http://www.icst.pku.edu.cn/cpdp/data/marmot_data.htm) where labelling several things such as document body, image area, table area, table caption and so on. This dataset specially use for document image analysis research purpose. They mentioned all coordinates in 16 digit hexa decimal with little endian format. Is there anyone how worked with this dataset and how to convert that 16 digit XY coordinate to human understandable format?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the clue after analysis and posting here if anyone need to investigate this dataset. However, they mentioned the unit value in which way they convert the given coordinate into pixel value but it was difficult to trace out because they did not mentioned it in their manual/guideline. They mentioned another place as an annotation.

1. First you have to convert their 16 character hexadecimal value using IEEE 754 little endian format. For example, a given coordinates for a label is,

   BBox=['4074145c00000005', '4074dd95999999a9', '4080921e74bc6a80', '406fb9999999999a']
2. Convert using python,

   conv_pound = struct.unpack('!d', str(t).decode('hex'))[0]) for t in BBox]
3. You will get value in "pound" unit which is 1/72 inch. We usually use coordinate in pixel unit and we know 1 inch is 96 pixel. So,

   conv_pound = [321.2724609375003, 333.8490234375009, 530.2648710937501, 253.8]

Then, divided each value by 72 and multiply with 96 to finally get corresponding pixel value which is,

```
in_pixel = [428.36328, 445.13203, 707.01983, 338.40000]
```

4. They started to count pixel position from bottom-left corner of the document image. If you consider from top-left corner (usually we consider in this way), you have to subtract 2nd and 4th value from image height. If we consider image [height, width] is [1123, 793] then we can represent the above coordinates in integer value as,

   label_boundary = [428, 678, 707, 785]

Comment: Step Number 4 seems to work only for very few images in the dataset and bounding boxes doesnt seem to match tables for most of the cases while plotting and viewing using matplotlib. What was the source of information to decode the data from xml

Comment: As @pv. mentioned, this approach works for the majority of the dataset. For few cases, the coordinates are either a little off, or are very off. I'm thinking these images' dpi is not 96. They have no dpi info, so it becomes hard to interpret those coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

After staring at the xmls for an hour, I've found the last missing piece in the answer by @MMReza:

You don't need to rely on the units of measure in (step number 3). There is an attribute called "CropBox" of the root element "Page". Use that one to scale the coordinates.
I have something along the following lines (also inverse y axis here):

```
px0, py1, px1, py0 = list(map(hex_to_double, page.get("CropBox").split()))
pw = abs(px1 - px0)
ph = abs(py1 - py0)

for table in page.findall(".//Composite[@Label='TableBody']"):
    x0p, y1m, x1p, y0m = list(map(hex_to_double, table.get("BBox").split()))
    x0 = round(imgw*(x0p - px0)/pw)
    x1 = round(imgw*(x1p - px0)/pw)
    y0 = round(imgh*(py1 - y0m)/ph)
    y1 = round(imgh*(py1 - y1m)/ph)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is trying to do this in Python 3 like I did, you only have to change step 2 of the other answer like this :

```
conv_pound = [struct.unpack('!d', bytes.fromhex(t))[0] for t in BBox]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to convert the coordinates as well as wanted to verify that my conversion actually worked. So, I made this script to read label file and respective image file then extract coordinates of table body(for eg) and visualize them on the images. It can be used to extract other fields in the similar manner. Comments explain it all

```
import glob
import struct
import cv2
import binascii
import re

xml_files = glob.glob("path_to_labeled_files/*.xml")

for i in xml_files:
    # Open the current file and read everything
    cur_file = open(i,"r") 
    content = cur_file.read()

    # Find index of all occurrences of only needed portions (eg TableBody this case)
    residxs = [l.start() for l in re.finditer('Label="TableBody"', content)]

    # Read the image
    img = cv2.imread("path_to_images_folder/"+i.split('/')[-1][:-3]+"jpg")

    # Traverse over all occurences
    for r in residxs[:-1]:
        # List to store output points
        coords = []

        # Start index of an occurence
        sidx = r

        # Substring from whole file content
        substr = content[sidx:sidx+400]

        # Now find start index and end index of coordinates in this substring  
        sidx = substr.find('BBox="')
        eidx = substr.find('" CLIDs')

        # String containing only points
        points = substr[sidx+6:eidx]

        # Make the conversion (also take care of little and big endian in unpack)
        bins = ''
        for j in points.split(' '):
            if(j == ''):
                continue
            coords.append(struct.unpack('>d', binascii.unhexlify(j))[0])

        if len(coords) != 4:
            continue

        # As suggested by MMReza
        for k in range(4):
            coords[k] = (coords[k]/72)*96
        coords[1] = img.shape[0] - coords[1]
        coords[3] = img.shape[0] - coords[3] 

        # Print the extracted coordinates
        print(coords)

        # Visualize it on the image
        cv2.rectangle(img, (int(coords[0]),int(coords[1]))  , (int(coords[2]),int(coords[3])), (255, 0, 0), 2) 
        cv2.imshow("frame",img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```